# Use Image in calculation if a certain property is given

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter

The goal is to select certain images from an image collection of Landsat 5 raw scenes, which possess a property called RADIANCE_MAXIMUM_BAND_6, since not all images contain this property.

`if (property === null) {
 var index = 0}
 else {
  index = 1}`

does not work, because apparently `null` is not the right condition, even if `print(property)` yields `null`

What's the right statement?

---

Rodrigo is right, this is neither specific enough nor an API friendly way. I think it would be easier with a filter

`var filtered = L5.filterMetadata('RADIANCE_MAXIMUM_BAND_6',"not_contains",null)`

and

`var filtered = L5.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(ee.List('RADIANCE_MAXIMUM_BAND_6')))`

doesnt work.

Which metadata is meant i.e. the properties of the Collection or those of the images?

to be specific: what I want to filter a Collection depending on if an Image has the property 'RADIANCE_MAXIMUM_BAND_6'. Because some images just do not have this property.

---

Comment: You should provide a reproducible code so we can better understand what's the issue and how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (the `aside(print)` is to see that the size changes):

```
var L5 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1");

var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([-121.96269531249999, 38.086752154007726]);

var filtered = L5
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .aside(print)
    .filter(ee.Filter.neq('RADIANCE_MAXIMUM_BAND_6', null))
    .aside(print);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var property = 6

property = property || "Nothing here"

if(property === "Nothing here"){
  print("zero", property)
}else{
 print("something Else:", property)
}
```

In the above example if your property is null or 0, it is given the value of "Nothing Here"

Then with a similar if statement you can check for "Nothing Here" and decide what to do next.

Comment: I guess this will not work because he may want to do this in a mapping function, thus it has to be "server side", and your solution will work only in the "client side". But he should modify the question to be more specific

Comment: i dont know wich value to use for "Nothing here" , and also  i agree with Rodrigo, there is Probably an API friendly way of doing so. I am just not experienced enough to find it